# Android - Class cloning not working

Tags: android, class, instance, clone, cloneable

```
public class UserWord extends WordADT {
     public int WORD_STATUS;
     public int POINT_OF_WORD;
     public int COUNT_OF_WRONG_ANSWER;

     @Override
     public Object getClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
         return super.clone();
     }
}
```

AND `

```
Userword temp = new Userword();
Usertword temp2 = temp.getClone();          //this way doesn't work.
```

I can't use getClone() method. I'm getting this error. How can i clone a instance?

> java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: Class UserWord doesn't implement Cloneable.

**Fixed:** clone:() method needs to implement *IClonable* inferface

Comment: put this instead of super and try

Comment: Show WordADT class please

Comment: WordADT just has a few int variables

Answer (score 1):

**Use it to clone any object :**

```
public static Object deepClone(Object object) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        return ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your case use like bellow:

```
Usertword temp2 = (Usertword)deepClone(temp);
```

Comment: Why not use the builtin clone method?

Comment: because built in clone method does not clone inner objects clone. I think this is a very good way to clone all objects from root

Comment: What makes you think OP wants that?

Comment: helped, tnx bro